# TextBox CSS Hover/Focus

Tags: css, textbox, styles

I added a nice box outline to my text box on focus, but want to add a grey outline on hover, but I ran into an issue. I need to display the box on hover when the textbox is not selected. Any way to do this? Thanks. =)

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
    border-color: #5AB0DB;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to do? What box do you want to display on hover? And what do you want to happen when it's the focus?

Comment: It's not at all clear what your problem is.

Comment: I need the grey outline (input:hover) to only display when the input is not focused(but still hovered over.).

Comment: So let me get this straight: given the code you've pasted above, you want it to ONLY have a `border-radius` when its hovered over and not focused? But if it's focused and you hover over it, you want it to be square again?

Comment: so you want the hover effect not to work if the box is focused?

Comment: Issue: http://i.imgur.com/azkm7.png

Answer (score 15):

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
border:1px solid #5AB0DB;
}

input[type="text"]:hover{
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover{
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
border:1px solid #5AB0DB;
border-radius:0;

}    ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/jCaGp/1/

I STRONGLY suggest setting the type as above otherwise every input element (buttons, selects, etc) will take on these effects.